# How to count the number of rows updated or inserted in table in jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a task in which I have to insert or update data in the table and those will show in the jsp page but I have to show the number of inserted or updated rows in the jsp page as per table. So I want to use jstl to do this. This is what I have done so far:

```
<logic:notEmpty name="inserted">            
<div align="left">  
    <table border="5px" >
    <strong><label><b>Inserted Details</b></label></strong>
        <tr>            

        <td width="30%" class="submitButton">
        CODE
        </td>
        <td width="180%" class="submitButton">
        DESCRIPTION
        </td>
        <td width="90%" class="submitButton">
        MRP
        </td>
        <td width="70%" class="submitButton">
        MOQ
        </td>
    </tr>       
      <logic:iterate name="inserted"   id="insertedId" >
    <tr>

    <c:set var="count" value="${0}"/>

      <td width="20%">
      <bean:write name="insertedId" property="code" />  
      </td>
      <td width="180%">
      <bean:write name="insertedId" property="description" />
      </td>
      <td width="90%">
      <bean:write name="insertedId" property="mrp" />
      </td >
      <td width="70%">
      <bean:write name="insertedId" property="moq" />
      </td>

    </tr>
     </logic:iterate>
</table>    
</div>
</logic:notEmpty>
```

This is the table for insertion where I will show the inserted values. Now I want to use a count value in jstl that will track the number of rows in the table. I have taken `<c:set var="count" value="${0}"/>` as the counter. But I cannot use the variable properly. I am new to jstl, somebody please help.

Comment: So, you actually want to display the size of the collection `inserted`, is that right? `${fn:length(inserted)}` or, in latest versions of the JSP spec, `${inserted.size()}`. Just to be clear: logic tags are not JSTL tags. They're part of Struts1 and were already documented as obsolete even when Struts1 itself wasn't an abandoned framework yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
//set your variable
<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />

//start loops here
<c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>
//end

//example print
<c:out value = "${count}">
```